# Finite extension of local field.

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

Let $F$ be a finite extension of $\Bbb{Q}_p$. Let K be  tamely ramified extension of $F$ Containing the maximal unramified extension. Let $P$ denote the residue field of the corresponding tamely ramified extension. Is there an easy way of showing that the natural map  $(O_K)\rightarrow P$, is injective on the roots of unity lying in $K$.

Comment: It’s unclear to me what you mean by “maximal tamely ramified extension of $F$”. Do you mean an extension that is totally ramified, and tamely so? Or do you mean an extension in which the only ramification is tame? The latter includes the maximal *unramified* extension of $F$, the former does not.

Comment: I mean only tamely ramified extension.

Comment: I don’t feel that you have answered my question. Does $K$ include the maximal unramified extension of $F$?

Comment: @lubin: yes. K include the maximal unramified extension of F

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extension $\Bbb Q_p(\zeta_p)\supset\Bbb Q_p$ is tamely ramified (degree is $p-1$), and the $p$-th roots of unity are sent to the identity in $\Bbb F_p$. (Perhaps I misunderstand your question?)

Comment: What I mean to say is here .See https://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/scripties/KretMaster.pdf

Comment: first line of page 56

Comment: To me, it looks like a mistake in the paper. Probably not essential, since the kernel of that map consists of no more than the $p$-th roots of unity. You can check it out for the case $p=2$, where of course $-1$ goes to the identity in $\Bbb F_2$.